# Java - Client giving error on connect

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, javafx

I am working on a simple Java messaging program. Before I begin working  on more complex features, I would like to get the basic system working. Currently

1. Multiple clients can connect
2. Multiple clients can send messages that the server receives
3. Server closes connections when the client is terminates

This code in particular appears to be what is giving the errors. It is the run() method in my ClientThread.java thread (that implements runnable). This thread is for handling incoming messages from the server (sending messages works fine).

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ClientThread implements Runnable{
    private Socket server;
    private DataInputStream in;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    public Text msgContent;
    public void login(Stage stage, Scene main, String username, String password, String portString, String host) {
    try {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(portString);
        this.server = new Socket(host, port);

        this.in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        this.out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
        stage.setScene(main);
        Platform.runLater(new ClientThread());
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Port");
        return;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error Connecting to Server");
        return;
    }
}
public void run() {
    String msg = "";

    try {

        while (true) {
            msg = in.readUTF(); //This line gives Errors
            System.out.println("Read message from server");
            msgContent.setText(msgContent.getText() + msg + "\n");
            System.out.println("Added message from server to view");
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to read message from server and add to view.");
    }

}
public void sendMsg(String msg) {
    try {
        out.writeUTF(msg);
    } catch (Exception ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Note that msgContent is a Text object in my JavaFX frontend and in the inputStream from the server. My full code is [here](https://github.com/xv435/JavaMSG/tree/master/src). The error I am getting is

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at ClientThread.run(ClientThread.java:42)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Failed to read message from server and add to view.

Also note that I am using Platform.runLater() to run this method. I want to know how to fix the above error so my code works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `in` null? We never see where it's defined or declared.

Comment: No. `in` is not null. Try the [GitHub Page](http://www.github.com/xv435/JavaMSG) to see the whole program.

Comment: An [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) posted inline in the question is better than a link to an offsite resource.

Comment: Added full ClientThread.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Cause of NullPointer Exception*

`in` is null.

Your NullPointerException occurs because in this call you create a new instance of the ClientManager class: `Platform.runLater(new ClientThread());`, so it won't use existing instance of ClientManager in which you have initialized the `in` and `out` members.  Instead, you could use `Platform.runLater(this);`, to get rid of your NullPointerException.

However, your code has other issues...

*Incorrect concurrent programming*

You are hanging the JavaFX application thread which will stop your application from rendering or responding to UI input.  Never busy wait the JavaFX application thread.

One way to accomplish what you are trying to do is to use the [JavaFX concurrency utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm), in particular a [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

Run the task on it's own thread, then it can loop, accepting input forever and it won't block your UI thread.  You can (perhaps) make your thread a non-daemon thread so that it exits automatically when all of the other daemon threads complete.  You could feed the input back to your UI using Platform.runLater. But, for the simple example you provided where you want to update some message text, instead you can invoke [updateMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateMessage-java.lang.String-) (note this does not need a Platform.runLater call as the Task class takes care of that kind of detail for you).  To get your message label updated, you can bind it's text property to the task's message property.  There are examples of how to do this in the Task javadoc.

Comment: Anyone looking a this thread might want to look [here](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2774481) for an example by the author of this question.